# Print "Jobs Finished" only when all the bjobs are completed

Tags: python, unix, parallel-processing, lsf, hpcc

I have a python script that submits multiple jobs using bjobs. Below is the code snippet

```
 for jobs in job_list:
    i=0
    os.system("bsub -J JOB_{} jobs".format(str(i))
    i+=1
```

I want to print "Finished runnning" only when all the jobs have completed.
How can I do the same ?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to get the result of each job, hence use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module instead.

if you are calling each job on a separate thread, you can use a shared list to for saving the result of each job, so whenever all get done, this list will be the same size as the `jobs_list`, then you can print the proper message.

but if the code is just the above snippet, you can do this:

```
for index, job in enumerate(job_list):
    result = subprocess.call(f"bsub -J JOB_{index} jobs")
print("Finished runnning")
```

Comment: What If I want to wait for all the jobs to be completed and then continue with the remaining script?

Comment: I edited my answer, call method is blocking, so it will not continue till the current subprocess gets done. `result` will be the subprocess return code, you can use it as further checks.
You'll find more detail here:
[subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Comment: wow thank you, that is what i wanted so far

Answer (score 0):

not sure... but please have a try this !!

```
counter = 0
for jobs in job_list:
    counter +=1
    i=0
    os.system("bsub -J JOB_{} jobs".format(str(i))
    i+=1
    if len(job_list) <= counter:
        print("Completed")
'''
```